# Which P value do I use?

Tags: regression, p-value

I have two different p-values here, do I use the Pr( t ) or the regular p-value?

```
Call:
lm(formula = ddd ~ CON, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5726 -0.4859 -0.4570  0.5141  0.5430 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.60144    0.09117  17.565   <2e-16 ***
CON         -0.02889    0.02360  -1.224    0.222    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5004 on 315 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.004735,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.001575 
F-statistic: 1.499 on 1 and 315 DF,  p-value: 0.2218
```

Comment: What model are you using?  There are p-values associated with regression parameters and for the overall fit F test.  So it depends on which one you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Because you fit a simple regression model (one covariate), so the p-value for slop (0.222) and overall F-test p-value (0.2218) are the same thing. If you ask the program give you one more digit on slop p-value, you will get 0.2218, instead of 0.222.

About p-value for intercept (<2e-16), I think you are not interested in it.